# Only Chrome freezes while page is loading (using jquery at domready)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am not quite sure how to explain this.. Let's try it:
I have a view to edit products and each product supports variations (as color, width, etc). Each variation is loaded by server-side and, then, I use jquery to load and format contents on those variations. At this point, only Chrome gets freezed for a while (at end It show the results).
I have to say that freeze time increase with more variations (obviously).

I tried to debug with no luck, the script pauses on breakpoints as normal.

To reproduce it just follow this steps:

```
1. log in at http://www.pgtopro.es (user@test.es, 1234)
2. go directly to http://www.pgtopro.es/Productos/Edit/1564?pg=0&catId=0&marcaId=0&orFi=0&orDe=False
```

Note: If disable Javascript or jQuery It works.

Thank you for reading, waiting for responses :)

Comment: Overload on javascript. maybe you are trying to do lot of manipulation on page load. Different browsers have different capability, so it will  not be same on  all browser.

Comment: Problem seems to with tiny_mce.js . Its too big plus may be its doing lot of processing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` uses `data-prefix` attribute on elements. Unfortunately, We are using `data-prefix` attribute in our javascript to manage the product variations and (**I think**) that provoked a little conflict.

I can't deepen much more because I haven't time to waste. Anyway, disabling the plugin or changing our `data-prefix` to `data-otherword` solves the problem.

Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you have a memory-eating usage of jQuery. This is cleaned up by GC.
GC is the thing that freezes your page.

Try to save memory with jquery.

If you select something with jQuery, do not call the selector every time.
Try save the object into a var

```
var jqObject = jQuery('#Object');
jqObject.attr('id' ,'foo');
jqObject.click(...
jqObject.show();
```

also you can pack your images into a sprite.

Some stuff to read:
http://jonraasch.com/blog/5-performance-tuning-tricks-for-jquery
http://davidwalsh.name/css-sprites

Comment: Thank you for answers. I know that jquery code is not optimized. I will optimize it maximum as possible with my knowledge.

I will notice the results tomorrow. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hello again.

I optimized the code and It looks much better... But window still freezes. Commenting each js separately I found the problem:     `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` .We are using mvc system and this js is loaded in the main layout, It has no relation with products' view. I will try to find some information about that (in work time, of course). Thank you all